# Proving that any $T : [0,\infty] \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that $T(\omega)\geq \omega$ is a stopping time.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\Omega=[0,\infty]$, $\mathcal{F}$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, $P$ is the Lebesgue measure.

We're to consider the following filtration: $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(\{I_{\{\omega\leq s\}}\}_{s\leq t})$.

The book I'm reading states that any measurable function $T : [0,\infty] \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that $T(\omega)\geq \omega$ is a stopping time.

**My try:**

By definition, we have $\{\omega\leq s\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$ for all $s\leq t$.
$$
\{T\leq t\}=\{\omega: \omega\leq T(\omega) \leq t\}= \{\omega: \omega\leq t\}\in \mathcal{F}_t.
$$

The equality comes from
$$
\{\omega: \omega\leq t\}=\{\omega: \omega \leq T(\omega)\leq t\}\cup \{\omega: T(\omega)< \omega \leq t\}.
$$
But the second set is empty since by assumption we always have $\omega\leq T(\omega)$.

Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the equality in the line second from the bottom, with $\{ \omega : \omega \le t\}$ on the left.  Why is the set $\{\omega : \omega \le t < T(\omega)\}$ or something similar not considered on the right hand side?

Comment: @user6247850 ups... you're right. Is there a way to prove then this?

Comment: $\{T\leq t\}\subset[0,t]$ for if $T(\omega)\leq t$, then $\omega\leq T(\omega)\leq t$. Thus, $\{T\leq t\}$ is a measurable subset of $[0,t]$; hence $\{T\leq t\}$ is in $\mathscr{B}([0,t])=\mathcal{F}_t$

Comment: Notice that $\sigma([0,s]: s\leq t)=\mathscr{B}([0,t])$, that is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the intervals $[0,s]$ with $0\leq s\leq t$ generates the Borel subsets of $[0,t]$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz could you please elaborate a bit your 1st comment? 1) You're saying that where I have equality in the bottom of my post, should be a \subset. 2) Why would a subset of [0,t] be immediately $\mathcal{F}_t $ -measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_t$ generated by the intervals $[0,s]$, $0\leq s\leq t$ is the same as the collection of Borel subsets of $[0,t]$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_t=\mathscr{B}([0,t])$: for any $0\leq a<b\leq t$, $(a,b]=[0,b]\setminus[0,a]\in\mathcal{F}_t$. The sets $(a,b]$ generate all Borel sets in $[0,t]$.

Assume that $T$ is Borel measurable, and that  $T(\omega)\leq \omega$ for all $\omega$.  For any $t\geq0$, $\{T\leq t\}\subset[0,t]$ a.s.,  for if $T(\omega)\leq t$, then $\omega\leq T(\omega)\leq t$ a.s. Thus, $\{T\leq t\}$ is a Borel measurable subset of $[0,t]$. This means that  $\{T\leq t\}\in \mathscr{B}([0,t])=\mathcal{F}_t$

For the general case where $T$ is Lebesgue measurable, choose $T''$ Borel measurable such that $T=T''$ almost surely, and  consider $T'(\omega)=T''(\omega)\wedge \omega$. Then $T'=T$ almost surely and satisfies $T'(\omega)\leq \omega$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I still have a doubt... $\{T\leq t\} \subset [0,t]$, yes, but why would this mean that it's a borel measurable subset?

Comment: In fact, $\{T\leq t\}$ is a Lebesgue subset of $[0,t]$ (I did not read your statement carefully) Under this condition, your filtrations are slightly small that what you need, so you may have to "complete" your filtrations $\mathcal{F}_t=\mathscr{B}([0,t])$ to be the collection of Lebesgue subsets of $[0,t]$. Not big deal, since as you know, every Lebesgue set $A$ equals almost surely a Borel set $A'$.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: Let me know if this answers you question. In the last edit to my answer, one works with $T'$ which is Borel. Then as $T=T'$ almost surely (a.s), the set $\{T\leq t\}=\{T'\leq t\}$ a.s and so, $\{T\leq t\}$ is a Lebesgue subset of $[0,t]$. As I said earlier. you need to complete the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ to include Lebesgue sets. That is a standard regularization procedure.

Comment: Oliver, I think you wanted to say that $T(\omega) \geq \omega$ for all $\omega$, right? Also, in that case, I think we would want the max instead of the min for $T''$.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. of course, $T'(\omega):=T''(\omega)\vee \omega\geq \omega$